# Custom auth token caching (SessionSecurityTokenCache override vs ITokenCacheRepository implementation)

Tags: session, caching, token

When implementing a custom SessionSecurityTokenCache, is it better to extend/override SessionSecurityTokenCache or to implement ITokenCacheRepository? And why?

I have working examples of both and though there are a few minor differences (different method signatures, Get() on an ITokenCacheRepository implementation is requested less frequently than when overriding Get() on SessionSecurityTokenCache), they seem to do roughly the same thing. There is quite a lot of conflicting documentation out there, so am not sure which route to take with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more reading on this, I found more info [here](http://brockallen.com/2013/02/21/server-side-session-token-caching-in-wif-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/) which hints at when to derive from SessionSecurityTokenCache.

For web based scenarios (as opposed to the WCF-based scenarios) we can derive from PassiveRepositorySessionSecurityTokenCache. It allows for a simpler custom implementation because there are some methods of the WIF SessionSecurityTokenCache base class that aren't needed in web-based scenarios.